# synthesize caller function when the callee functions are not synthesizable

Tags: xilinx

I am using Xilinx as a beginner and I am really get confused for one thing.

If the desired hardware function is synthesizable, but the called functions are not synthesizable, due to using array of pointers or malloc or calloc,
what would be expected in Xilinx?

Why Xilinx cannot map that top level hardware function to FPGA or can not make it as synthesizable?

Is this only for callee functions which are not synthesizable?

Comment: Is this a [tag:vhdl] or [tag:verilog] question? Just imagine what does it mean to have infinite dynamic memory allocation in an FPGA ... the FPGA would need to generate or destroy flip-flops / transistors at runtime ... so you need tiny soldering-minions in an FPGA to create such a device.